# How to return JSX inside setInterval in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, return, setinterval, jsx

I need to retun JSX but I am not getting how to perform this bcz setInterval is not returning JSX. Can I opt any other way or modify the same code :

```
renderCountdown = (start) => {
    let appointmentDuration = new Date(this.state.appointmentEndDate).getTime() - new Date(this.state.appointmentStartDate).getTime();
    let countDownDate = new Date(this.state.appointmentStartDate).getTime();
    let countDownTime = countDownDate;
    let x = setInterval(() => {
        let now = new Date().getTime();
        let distance = countDownDate - now;
        // console.log('distance--------', distance);
        let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        // console.log('days------', days);
        let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        let countdown = days + 'd ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's ';
        if (distance === 0) {
            return (
                <button className="message button clickable" onClick={start}>Click to Start Call </button>
            );
        } else if (distance > 0) {
            return (
                <p> <b>Appointment starts in :</b> <span>{countdown}</span></p>
            );
        } else if (distance < 0) {
            return (
                <h2>Appointment Expired</h2>
            );
            clearInterval(x);
        };
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cant help you how to return jsx in setInterval, but there is a simple way to slove your problem. You will have a state called `distance`. And every seconds will decrease that state. in render you you check value of distance and render what you want. Here is sample code

```
constructor(props) {
  //calc countDownDate
  //now can access props 
  this.state = {
    distance: countDownDate - now;
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.countDown = setInterval(() => {
    const {distance} = this.state
    //Calc the new distance
    if(distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(this.countDown)
    }
    this.setState({distance: newDistance})
  }, 1000)
}


componentWillUnount() {
  clearInterval(this.countDown)
}


render() {
  const {distance} = this.state
  if (distance === 0) {
        return (
            <button className="message button clickable" onClick={start}>Click to Start Call </button>
        );
    } else if (distance > 0) {
        return (
            <p> <b>Appointment starts in :</b> <span>{countdown}</span></p>
        );
    } else if (distance < 0) {
        return (
            <h2>Appointment Expired</h2>
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: I am getting my countDownDate using nextProps, So I am not getting how to manage that into the state ?

Comment: By d way your solution will work if my scenario is not considered

Comment: I edited a answer. See update from constructor. Hope it will help you